# Automatic detection best format to render PDF to bitmap (jpg or png)

Tags: bitmap, png, rendering, jpeg

My software is rendering PDF pages as bitmaps to the browser.

For PDF documents containing a lot of text it is better to render the pages as **PNG**. When I would render such a PDF to JPG I get [jpg artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact)

For PDF documents containing photo's it is better to render the pages as **JPG**. When I would render such a PDF to PNG it will become huge.

Do you have idea's to determine (automatically) which render format to choose?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Make your software decide on the amount of images - something like a ratio of their areas, compared to the page size. (What ratio is "best" to split on is something you need to determine.)

Comment: @jongware: Thanks, this could work. I am currently testing another method: I calculate the average page size (in bytes). When this is greater than a certain value I decide to render as JPG. I expect that PDF's with a lot of images will have a greater average page size than a PDF containing mainly text.